# SalesForce is it possible to have a variable which updates globally?

Tags: salesforce, apex

We have an email service, where leads are automatically imported. Here we need to assign the lead for every import to a different person. We have a drop down field to do so, so that is not the problem.

The idea would be, to have an integer which works like this: We get an email, if the integer is 1, the lead is assigned to person 1, then the 1 gets incremented and for the next email which is incoming, the int should be 2. Is this somehow possible, to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're too many built declarative ways of assigning leads in salesforce so I would not recommend trying to do this with apex.

Have you checked out [lead assignment rules and queues](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_assign.htm&language=en_US)?

Comment: Oh, looks fantastic! How did I not find this before?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could just create a custom object like email_settings__c with a field called lead_assigned.  Then your code could read for that field, get the value and update the field for the next go around.  This is assuming that you are sending the emails via a trigger.

Comment: I think it was a little bit bad written by me. We have a field which is called "Maklerbetreuer" which is the guy who has to call the lead. When the last lead goes to maklerbetreuer 1, the next should go to maklerbetreuer 2. We have a solution now to pull the last lead with "ORDER BY created_date" and read our field of this one...